# Vows callback testing in Node.js generating anonymous errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, bdd, vows

I am new to the continuation passing style of asynchronous computation used in Node.js applications, and I'm struggling to get a grip on some fairly basic code.

I am trying to write a library which will create an imap interface to imap.gmail.com, and I am trying to follow BDD with 'vows'.js' (with varying levels of success. I'm definitely not following the full red->code->green cycle that I should be, but it's hard to get started in a language that way).

The relevant test case looks like this:

```
var gmail = require('../lib/gmail.js'),
    vows = require('vows'),
    assert = require('assert'),
    fs = require('fs');

vows.describe('Basic interface tests').addBatch({
  'A GMailInterface object can': {
    topic: function() {
      var gm = Object.create(gmail.GMailInterface);
      var settings_file = 'test/test_settings.json';
      var settings = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(settings_file));
      var that = this;
      gm.connect(settings.email,settings.password,function() {
        that.callback(gm); // ERROR BEING GENERATED HERE
      });
    },
     // ACTUAL VOWS OMITTED - the following is just a test of the callback
    'find an email' : {
      topic: function(gm) {
        console.log(">>>",gm);
      },
    }
  }
}).export(module)
```

If I write a console.log message right above the line with "ERROR BEING GENERATED HERE", it will print. It will not if I put a message below it. The output of the test gives the following error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Uncaught, unspecified 'error' event.
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (events.js:50:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (/Users/eblume/Repositories/my_stuff/gmail/node_modules/vows/lib/vows.js:236:24)
    at /Users/eblume/Repositories/my_stuff/gmail/node_modules/vows/lib/vows/context.js:31:52
    at Object.callback (/Users/eblume/Repositories/my_stuff/gmail/node_modules/vows/lib/vows/context.js:46:29)
    at Array.0 (/Users/eblume/Repositories/my_stuff/gmail/test/gmail_test.js:17:14)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

The code in gmail.js is a bit too much to post here, but here is what I think is the relevant section - I can post more if you ask a question below.

```
gm.connect = function(username,password,cb) {
  var self = this;
  self.conn = new ImapConnection({
    username: username,
    password: password,
    host: 'imap.gmail.com',
    port: 993,
    secure: true
  });

  async.series([
    function(callback){self.conn.connect(callback); },
    function(callback){self.conn.openBox('[Gmail]/All Mail',true,callback);}
  ],
  function(err,results) {
    if (err) {
      die(err);
    }
    process.nextTick(cb);
  });
};
```

Where might I be going wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: To future people with similar issues - I simply switched to 'mocha', which is a much nicer BDD testing framework, in my opinion. It gave me a much more concise and easy to understand error, and soon fixed my issue (which was actually a run-away event loop in the connection started in a different function.)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading up on how 'this' works. If nobody's been messing with it the 'that' of `that.callback` refers to the parent object which is labeled with a literal string as 'A GMailInterface object can' .

I suspect it's the this factor tripping you up. 'callback' should be defined as a method of the same object as the 'topic' method the way you have things set up and that doesn't strike me as the way it's meant to work.

'this' typically refers to nearest ancestor/parent object by default. It ignores wrapping functions unless they're used as constructors using the 'new' keyword in which case it indicates the object instance. In the case of event callbacks in the DOM (browser JS - not node.js which I don't know in-depth as far as events), it typically refers to the object that's had an event triggered on it.

There's no real kludge being fixed with that and self. We just tend to use those to be certain we're addressing the top object in cases where an object has aggregate objects.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - and you're absolutely right that I need to investigate the binding of 'this' more thoroughly. However, based on the [vows documentation](http://vowsjs.org/) (check the last example in the darkest part towards the top - the one about peeling bananas asynchronously), it looks like `this` is getting bound to something that does actually have the `callback` method by `vows` itself.

This is confirmed by swapping out `gm` in the args of `callback` for something else like `true`, which prints ">>>true" to the console and then hangs indefinitely.

Comment: Okay, well, in the examples I'm seeing use of the new keyword for the thing being assigned to 'topic.' That means an object is being created. topic is likely being hit by the event that's being reacted to, so is the likely target of this.